# mxGraph editor - node cloning on drag?

Tags: java, graph, editor

I'm customizing mxGraph java editor that comes with jGraph. What happens with the `value` object when a node is "cloned" by dragging an edge out of it? Does the new node share the same value object with the parent one? How is it possible to override any default behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you drag an edge out of a vertex and create a new vertex, a complete clone of the cell is created. If you look in com.mxgraph.model.mxCell the clone() method calls cloneValue(). The default user object (the value) is an XML Node and uses cloneNode on the DOM API. If you wants to change the default behaviour, you could override mxCell for your particular cell type(s) and implement cloneValue() to do something else.